# Explode string in PHP that contain brackets and semicolon

Tags: php, arrays, string

**Problem:**

I have a string that looks like this:

```
[1=>2,3,4][5=>6,7,8][9=>10,11,12][13=>14,15][16=>17,18]
```

**Question:**

How can you get that string into this?

```
1
    2
    3
    4
5
    6
    7
    8
9
    10
    11
    12
13
    14
    15
16
    17
    18
```

Comment: You can probably use reg expressions and groups - but as Carsten says, what did you try so far?

Comment: Maybe not useful : you seem to have tried to use a custom format to serialize an array, look at php serialize() or json_encode()

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
$str = "[1=>2,3,4][5=>6,7,8][9=>10,11,12][13=>14,15][16=>17,18]";
$str = explode("]", $str);
$finalResult = array();

foreach ($str as $element) {
    if (!empty($element)) {
        $element = substr($element, 1);
        $element = explode("=>", $element);

        // element[0] contains the key
        $element[1] = explode(",", $element[1]);
        $finalResult[$element[0]] = $element[1];
    }
}

print_r($finalResult);
```

Answer (score 2):

I will try with:

```
$input  = '[1=>2,3,4][5=>6,7,8][9=>10,11,12][13=>14,15][16=>17,18]';
$output = array();

preg_match_all('\[(\d+)=>([\d,]+)\]', $input, $matches);
foreach ($matches as $group) {
  $output[$group[1])] = explode(',', $group[2]);
}

// and print result out:

foreach ( $output as $key => $val ) {
  echo $key . '<br/>';
  foreach ( $val as $v ) {
    echo '    ' . $v . '<br/>';
  }
}
```

Answer (score 2):

This code:

```
$input  = '[1=>2,3,4][5=>6,7,8][9=>10,11,12][13=>14,15][16=>17,18]';
$regex  = '~\[(?P<keys>\d)+=>(?P<values>(?:\d+,?)+)\]~';
$result = array();

if (preg_match_all($regex, $input, $matches)) {
  foreach ($matches['keys'] as $key => $value) {
    $result[$value] = explode(',', $matches['values'][$key]);
  }
}

print_r($result);
```

Results to this:

```
Array
(
    [1] => Array
        (
            [0] => 2
            [1] => 3
            [2] => 4
        )

    [5] => Array
        (
            [0] => 6
            [1] => 7
            [2] => 8
        )

    [9] => Array
        (
            [0] => 10
            [1] => 11
            [2] => 12
        )

    [3] => Array
        (
            [0] => 14
            [1] => 15
        )

    [6] => Array
        (
            [0] => 17
            [1] => 18
        )

)
```

Answer (score 1):

```
<?php
$str = "[1=>2,3,4][5=>6,7,8][9=>10,11,12][13=>14,15][16=>17,18]";
$parts1 = explode("][",$str);

$parts1[0]=str_replace("[","",$parts1[0]);
$parts1[count($parts1)-1]=str_replace("]","",$parts1[count($parts1)-1]);

foreach($parts1 as $k=>$v){
    $parts2[]=explode("=>",$v);
}

foreach($parts2 as $k=>$v){
    echo "<div>".$v[0]."</div>";
    foreach(explode(",",$v[1]) as $key=>$value){
        echo "<div style='margin-left:20px'>".$value."</div>";
    }
}
```

Output Would be
[image]

Answer (score 1):

Using only `str_replace()`:

```
$dict = array(
    '=>' => "\n\t",
    ','  => "\n\t",
    '][' => "\n",
    '['  => '',
    ']'  => '',
);

echo str_replace(array_keys($dict), array_values($dict), $str);
```

Will give the result you want.

Comment: Thank you for the solution but I made a mistake not mentioning it should be in an array.